# How to incorporate matlab into jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda, jupyter

I am trying to integrate MATLAB and jupyter notebook so that I can use MATLAB in the web based notebooks and lab. I am running MATLAB R2020a, python 3.6 (from conda 4.8.2); the computer’s OS is Ubuntu 18.04. I am getting an error saying the MATLAB engine is not installed, though as far as I can tell it has been installed.

I have performed the following steps:
    1. I made a conda environment with python 3.6 `conda create matlab-conda python=3.6`.
    2. From there, I installed matlab_kernel using pip by typing in `pip install matlab-kernel`.
    3. If I check that the kernel is installed by keying in `jupyter kernelspec list` and the view the lists, it says:
           Available kernels:

> ir         /home/computerone/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
>
> matlab
>   /home/computerone/miniconda3/envs/matlab-conda/share/jupyter/kernels/matlab
>
> python3
>   /home/computerone/miniconda3/envs/matlab-conda/share/jupyter/kernels/python3

4. To configure MATLAB, I located the extern/engines/python folder, and from within conda env ran the setup: `python setup.py install`. This successfully ran.

When I open the juyter notebook or lab, the MATLAB notebook option is there and I can select it, revealing a notebook; however, when I open a MATLABnotebook and type a command (e.g., 2+5), the following error is thrown:

```
[MetaKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computerone/miniconda3/envs/matlab-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "/home/computerone/miniconda3/envs/matlab-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/computerone/miniconda3/envs/matlab-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/home/computerone/miniconda3/envs/matlab-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 541, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin,
  File "/home/computerone/miniconda3/envs/matlab-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/metakernel/_metakernel.py", line 395, in do_execute
    retval = self.do_execute_direct(code)
  File "/home/computerone/miniconda3/envs/matlab-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab_kernel/kernel.py", line 99, in do_execute_direct
    retval = self._execute_async(code)
  File "/home/computerone/miniconda3/envs/matlab-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab_kernel/kernel.py", line 257, in _execute_async
    future = self._matlab.eval(code, **kwargs)
  File "/home/computerone/miniconda3/envs/matlab-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab_kernel/kernel.py", line 81, in _matlab
    """)
ImportError: 
        Matlab engine not installed:
        See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.htm
```

Comment: Please format your code so that errors stand out.

Comment: https://am111.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jmatlab_use.html

Comment: I am not sure but MATLAB usually does not distributes its kernel for free. It might be that it is just an interface and you still need to install the standard MATLAB 2020a on your system

Comment: @Joe : Thanks for your reply. The list of instructions you listed are the ones that I have followed. The code should be formatted correctly..... If I can change anything in particular please let me know.

Comment: @max MATLAB R2020a is installed and if I run through matlab directly it works fine. For same reason, jupyter isn't recognizing the engine. Any advice you may have woul be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you do https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html

Comment: and https://am111.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jmatlab_install.html#(2)-MATLAB-side-configuration